# I would like several subdomains to show the main domain on apache/php

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I have www.domain.com

I also have de.domain.com and cn.domain.com

I want all these subdomains to load the same site (the main www site).

There is code within my site to evaluate the subdomain and show the appropriate language content based on it.

Is this something I can do within .htaccess?

Comment: What's the code within your site that evaluates the subdomain? Do you have anything in your htaccess file?

Comment: The code that evaluates is already in place and works fine - its been working on the client's Win server for years. It should work fine on the Linux server as well and is not relevant to this question.

What I need to know is how I make the alternate subdomains load the main site when someone visits.

Comment: htaccess is currently empty

Comment: "*What I need to know is how I make the alternate subdomains load the main site when someone visits*" that depends entirely on how everything is set up. Whatever you do is going to have to work in close conjunction with how your subdomain coding works.

Comment: I don't mean they need to load the main site content - what I mean is that it will load the content that is appropriate for that subdomain. I can paste a bunch of ExpressionEngine CMS code here that tells you how it determines whether is should show english content, german content, or chinese content, but that isn't going to get me closer to the answer. 

What will get me there is to know what code to put into htaccess that, when de.domain.com and ch.domain.com is in the URL address bar, will run the main www site. EE will take it from there and show the right content.

Comment: First think about what have been changed from the windows server to the new server. Have the web server changed? Have you migrated the configurations? Did he have an .htaccess with content previously or a web.config if it was IIS and not apache? There are plenty of questions needed to actually answer your question and if you want an answer I recommend you to go after it.